# Yii2 : Getting values from pop up in controller

Tags: php, post, http-post, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using yii2-advanced-app & want to send username & password to my siteController using post method. I don't want to use hidden form fields here.

I'm tried it in this way :

my popup located in index.php is -

```
<form id = "userlogin" action = "index.php?r=site/loginpopup" method = "POST">
                    <label>Email / Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="getCred()"><a href="javascript: getCred()" name='login-button' class="btn btn_red">Login</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var userloginValidator = new Validator("userlogin");
                userloginValidator.addValidation("username","req", "Please enter the value for query");
                function getCred(){
                    var un = document.getElementById('username').value;
                    var pwd = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    alert(un);alert(pwd);
                    // window.location = "index.php?r=site/loginpopup&username="+un+"&password="+pwd;
                    if(document.userlogin.onsubmit()) {
                        document.userlogin.submit();
                    }
                    $.post("index.php?r=site/loginpopup", { username: un }, { password: pwd });
                    // jQuery.post('index.php?r=site/loginpopup',{ username: un }, { password: pwd });
                }
                </script>
```

And the controller function is -

```
public function actionLoginpopup()
    {
$un = $_POST['username'];
echo $un;
        exit();
}
```

But, it says -

Bad Request (#400)
Unable to verify your data submission.

Answer (score 0):

I think You cannot post a multipart form data with jquery post method

try to use Yii2 form and put this line

> 'enctype'          => 'multipart/form-data'
>   in the form options like this :

```
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id'      => 'userlogin',
    'method'  =>'post',
    'action'  => Url::toRoute['site/loginpopup'],
    'options' => [
        'enctype'          => 'multipart/form-data'
    ],
]); ?>
```

[YiiForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html#)